# Trying to figure out what a MySQL query does (not mine)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following MySQL tables that probably relate to this query:

```
Table: user_follow
Columns:   |  Type:
-----------|---------
id         |  INT(11)
follower   |  INT(11)
user       |  INT(11)
subscribed |  INT(11)
```

The ID is the ID of the follow, the follower is the person who is following the user, and subscribed is when they followed them. The follower and user will be the IDs of the people in the users table:

```
Table: users
Columns:  |  Type:
----------|---------
id        |  INT(11)
username  |  INT(11)
```

That is not the full users table, but that should be enough for whatever this MySQL query is doing. The ID in the users table is the user's ID, and the username is the username. So here is the query that I am trying to figure out what it is doing. I believe it is trying to get the username from the database of the user:

```
SELECT `ufollower`.`id` AS follower_id, `ufollower`.`username` AS follower_name,
     `ufollowed`.`id` AS user_id, `ufollowed`.`username` AS user_name
FROM `user_follow`
JOIN users ufollower ON `ufollower`.`id` = `user_follow`.`follower`
JOIN users ufollowed ON `ufollowed`.`id` = `user_follow`.`user`
WHERE `user_follow`.`user` = :p_id
```

The full code that I am trying to run is this (includes the query):

```
//Get people who this person is following
$following = $db->prepare("SELECT `ufollower`.`id` AS follower_id, `ufollower`.`username` AS follower_name, `ufollowed`.`id` AS user_id, `ufollowed`.`username` AS user_name FROM `user_follow` JOIN users ufollower ON `ufollower`.`id` = `user_follow`.`follower` JOIN users ufollowed ON `ufollowed`.`id` = `user_follow`.`user` WHERE `user_follow`.`user` = :p_id");
$following->bindValue(":p_id",$p_id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$following->execute();
$following = $following->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($following);

//If I do $following = $following->fetch(); and var_dump that, it returns "bool(false)" which I learned the other day that it couldn't do the query or there were no results found or something
```

Also, I am not an expert with MySQL, so if you could provide an answer that might work too, that would be great. I can do simple queries, but when it comes to joining tables, I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: yes, getting a boolean false back from a fetch operation means there's no more (or there never was any) data available for fetching.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct. Apparently this query looks like it is getting who is following the person, not who the person is following.

Comment: Nothing to do but when you bind an ID (integer), use instead the flag `PDO::PARAM_INT`

Comment: Yeah, I've been using PDO::PARAM_STR the whole time and wondering when I should use PARAM_INT, but it seems to be working anyways. Should I switch all integers to PDO::PARAM_INT, or only IDs? Usually when I am inserting in the database, I have a bunch of question marks for the values, and then do `$query->execute(array($something,$something));` Does that automatically do INTs as PARAM_INT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically user_follow table connects two other users, one that is following the other and this query gets those two users for one specific following.

This query explained could be described as:
For the user_follow with id :id get one user (ufollower) that is following another user (ufollowing) and their id and usernames.